# Let $H \leq G$ for some group G and $x\in G$. The conjugate of $H$ by $x$ is the set $xHx^{-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $H \leq G$ for some group G and $x\in G$. The conjugate of $H$ by $x$ is the set $xHx^{-1}$

(a) prove that $xHx^{-1} \leq G$ for all $x \in G$

(b) prove that if $K=xHx^{-1}$ for some $H \leq G$, then $HK\neq G$(i.e prove that a group cannot be the product of two conjugate subgroups ) You may assume proper subgroup H of G.

I have done part (a) and I totally understand it. but, I have no idea how would I start (b)

Answer (score 0):

If $x\in H$ the claim is clear since then $HK = H\neq G$. Assume that $x\notin H$. Suppose $HK = G$. Then there exist $h_1,h_2\in H$ such that $h_1xh_2x^{-1} = x^{-1}$. But then $x = h_1^{-1}h_2^{-1}\in H$. Contradiction.

Comment: Did you assume HK=H because that one of the conjugate subgroups of H is H itself (since multiplication by G on G from the right and from the left is a bijection?

Comment: I did not **assume** $HK=H$, but I inferred it. And - correct - that follows from $K = xHx^{-1} = H$ if $x\in H$. So, $HK = HH = H$.

Comment: I see how you got the $h_1xh_2x^{-1}$ since that's just $HK$ rewritten, but where did the "$=x^{-1}$"? What simple thing am I missing there?

Comment: I just took it. We have $x^{-1}\in G$. So, by assumption, $x^{-1}\in HK$. But that cannot be true.